# Kernel did not upgrade between 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, boot, 16.04, upgrade, kernel

Yesterday I upgraded my Ubuntu Desktop from LTS 14.04 to LTS 16.04. I did it via Software Updater.

There were several errors during the upgrade (is there a place where these errors are listed in the system so I can post it here?). The last one of them was at the end, saying that the boot partition was full. Following a post, I deleted a few kernels which I thought were old.

Now when I do `uname -r` it tells me that the kernel version is 3.13.0-93-generic, but it should be 4.4 something right? Can it be that I deleted the correct kernel by mistake? If yes, how do I fix this?

But the command `cat /etc/os-release` shows:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.1 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

The system seems to think it is 16.04 but I have a feeling there are many other wrong things, I just don't know how to find these upgrade errors.

Is there an official ubuntu post upgrade script that checks if everything is ok?

I don't know if it adds anything, but two other errors that I remember were that the ubuntu software center did not work after the upgrade, I fixed following a post that said it had something to do with a language setting. The other error was that on boot it showed "Lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit" which I fixed by edditing the GRUB file.

Anyways, I just want to know if my system is ok and what is the meaning of this contradiction between the kernel and the system version (if 16.04 had the wrong kernel would it even boot?)

Thank you very much in advance for any help!!!

**Edit:** Here is what I have installed (output of `dpkg -l | grep linux-image`):

```
linux-image-3.11.0-19-generic                                                               
linux-image-3.11.0-20-generic                                                               
linux-image-3.11.0-22-generic                                                              
linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic                                                              
linux-image-extra-3.11.0-19-generic                                                          
linux-image-extra-3.11.0-20-generic                                                          
linux-image-extra-3.11.0-22-generic                                                       
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic
```

Comment: Ok, let's not panic Can you check what kernels are installed with `dpkg -l | grep linux-image`, and append the output to the question.

Comment: I added the dpkg -l result to my original post, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

This happens sometimes for some reason.

It can be easily fixed in 16.04 by

```
sudo apt install linux-generic
```

This will install the correct kernel and the meta package for kernel upgrades.

Comment: If I do that will my system boot correctly? Any way I can check if there are any other errors with the upgrade? Thanks!

Comment: The system should boot OK. If it does not you can always boot with an old kernel using grub menu.

Comment: How do I boot an old kernel using grub? Old kernels are listed there?

Comment: I did sudo apt install linux-generic as you suggested and it worked, but now my vmware workstation wont start. But that is a different problem, I will ask a new question about it. Just to make sure though, is there anything else I need to check on the upgrade other than the kernel? Is there any Ubuntu script that checks that the upgrade is ok, including repositories, etc?

Comment: You can run `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` it should upgrade all packages to the latest ones in Xenial.

Comment: Thanks, I did that and it said there was nothing to update/upgrade. I hope this means my upgrade to 16.04 is ok.

Comment: @linux.girl: As you’re a reputation 11 user: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the “0” at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!