# Upgraded to 16.04 LTS server but still have 3.13.0-101 kernel

Tags: 16.04, kernel, do-release-upgrade

I ran *do-release-upgrade* on one of my 14.04 LTS servers, got no errors and it runs, but I notice that it still has the 3.13.0-101 kernel (and only that version, all earlier kernels and all header files were deleted). A 16.04 LTS server instance on AWS has kernel version 4.4.0-47. Did something go wrong on my local server upgrade? How do I get the v4 kernel, or is that not a problem?

Comment: Have you checked that your /etc/apt/sources.list is up to date (to reflect Xenial)? The new kernel should be installed via apt.

Comment: Does `$ dpkg --list | head -n 5 ; dpkg --list | grep -E '^[Hh]'` list any kernel packages? i.e. do you have a "Hold" on the 3 kernel or a related package?

Comment: @Matt O. Yes, it reflects the Xenial repositories.   But wouldn't you know it, even though I searched all over, once I posted my question a [related link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/815002/kernel-did-not-upgrade-between-14-04-lts-to-16-04-lts?rq=1) appeared that already has the answer and it worked.

Comment: @Hannu The *dpkg* commands show 4.4.0-47.68 did get installed but where did it go? *sudo apt install linux-generic* installed 4.4.0.47.50.

Comment: @greybeard That's kind of funny, I probably should've suggest it off the bat, but that's  more or less what I was getting at.