# Ubuntu Server upgrade 14.04 to 16.04 (in a container) did not update Kernel

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, kernel

I recently tried to upgrade a vserver to 16.04. While everything was smooth sailing, the kernel version is not updated whatever i do.

The correct packages seem to be installed:

`dpkg -l | grep linux-image`:

```
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic       4.4.0-57.78                             amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic 4.4.0-57.78                             amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                4.4.0.57.60                             amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

`lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

`ls -la /boot`:

```
-rw-------  1 root root  3875329 Dec 10 05:04 System.map-4.4.0-57-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1243800 Dec 10 05:04 abi-4.4.0-57-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   189991 Dec 10 05:04 config-4.4.0-57-generic
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Jan  1 11:45 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 31042421 Jan  1 11:45 initrd.img-4.4.0-57-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  7067152 Dec 10 05:04 vmlinuz-4.4.0-57-generic
```

...but still, when doing `uname -a` i get

```
Linux <hostname> 3.13.0-042stab116.1 #1 SMP Wed May 4 16:21:02 MSK 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

which is definitely the wrong kernel version. following the question [Kernel did not upgrade between 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815002/kernel-did-not-upgrade-between-14-04-lts-to-16-04-lts,i) tried `sudo apt install linux-generic` and `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`, but to no avail, the kernel version stays stubborn on 3.13.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm at fault. The vserver is of course running in a container, which means that there is no way to access the kernel, since the kernel belongs to the container host.